# MS Access VBA - why doesn't this work? How to handle variables in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

the part i was struggling with was getting SQL to recognize variables while keeping the SQL valid.

```
sub runsQL()

L = 5369
H = 5310

For i = 91 To 358

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [ResultsXL] SET [ResultsXL].DateID = " & i & "WHERE ((([ ResultsXL].ResID)>" & L & "And ([ResultsXL].ResID)<=" & H & "));"

L = L + 59
H = H + 59
next I
end sub
```

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just ignore the spaces:

```
"UPDATE [ResultsXL] SET [ResultsXL].DateID = " & i & " WHERE ([ ResultsXL].ResID > " & L & " And [ResultsXL].ResID <= " & H & ");"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Not familiar as I should be with MS Access SQL.
Need to "brush up".
Not pretty but it works

```
Dim L As Long
Dim H As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim strSQL As String


L = 15222
H = 15281
I = 259

DoCmd.SetWarnings False


For I = 259 To 358
```

this is where I was struggling...getting SQL to take variables

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Copy Of ResultsXL] SET [Copy Of ResultsXL].DateID =" & I & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE ((([Copy Of ResultsXL].ResID)>" & L & "And ([Copy Of ResultsXL].ResID)<=" & H & "));"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
L = L + 59
H = H + 59

Next I
```